# OpenCV unresolved external errors with objdetect.hpp functions (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, lnk2019

I'm trying to compile a simple face detection program in C++ in VS2010 and have come across two LNK 2019 errors:

> Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade referenced in function _main
>
> Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvHaarDetectObjects referenced in function "void __cdecl detectFaces(struct _IplImage *)" (?detectFaces@@YAXPAU_IplImage@@@Z)

Relevant code lines:

```
cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade );
```

...

```
  CvSeq *faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(  img,  cascade,  storage,  1.1,  3,  0, /*CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNNING*/  cvSize( 40, 40 ) );
```

I couldn't really find many references to this particular issue and I believe all the relevant libraries/directories are as they should be for the solution.

When I go to the function definitions it finds them in objdetect.hpp but what I don't understand is why I'm getting these LNK errors?

Comment: Does the project you are compiling knows the location of the library where the library is present?

Comment: PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV2.2\bin

Library dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV2.2\vs2010Build\lib\Debug

Additional dependencies:
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV2.2\vs2010Build\lib\Debug\opencv_core220d.lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV2.2\vs2010Build\lib\Debug\opencv_highgui220d.lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV2.2\vs2010Build\lib\Debug\opencv_video220d.lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV2.2\vs2010Build\lib\Debug\opencv_ml220d.lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV2.2\vs2010Build\lib\Debug\opencv_legacy220d.lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV2.2\vs2010Build\lib\Debug\opencv_imgproc220d.lib

Comment: Sorry, character limit and lack of formatting may make that harder to read. I believe the above should be sufficient as it's been fine for other openCV projects I've used thus far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added the libraries to your link dependencies?

right-click on your project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

Comment: I realised that a lack of caffeine this morning made forget to add as an additional dependency opencv_objdetect220d.lib
Thanks, it did prompt me to cross reference what I had already vs libraries in the folder left over

Answer (score 5):

Try to include opencv_objdetect220d.lib too. It worked like a charm.