# Where is cvaux230d.lib in OpenCV 2.3?

Tags: c, windows, opencv

I am trying to run a face tracking program in Visual Studio 2010 using OpenCV 2.3.  This particular program that I am trying to run was made on OpenCV 1.0.  So far, I am getting two linker errors:

```
1>facedet.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade referenced in function closeFaceDet
1>facedet.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvHaarDetectObjects referenced in function detectFace
```

Reading up online ( http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/opencv-2-3-error-in-visual-studio-10-0-td6811110.html ) about why these two errors appear, I have found that a potential solution is linking the cvaux230d.lib file.  However, this file does not seem to exist anywhere in the OpenCV I installed (OpenCV 2.3 binary package "OpenCV superpack").  Where can I find this file, or find an appropriate workaround?

In general, is it possible to run OpenCV 1.0 code using OpenCV 2.3?  What are potential fixes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826044/opencv-unresolved-external-errors-with-objdetect-hpp-functions-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OpenCV 2.3. those symbols are defined in **opencv_objdetect230d.lib**